# How to unserialize() data string when an url inside it has to be changed?

Tags: php, serialization, wordpress

In WordPress you can save post custom information in the form of post meta.
SO I have saved to input fields value in one meta field in the form of serialized array like this.

```
a:2:{i:0;s:81:"http://sme.sabidoclick.com/sme/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/L-Mini-Instructions.pdf";i:1;s:85:"http://sme.sabidoclick.com/sme/test/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/L-Mini-Graphic-Template.pdf";
```

So as you can see in the string "i:0;s:81:" this "81" is the length of the next url.
and before transferring the site to new domain I have replaced the url in the database file now the url is changed and the new array is.

```
a:2:{i:0;s:81:"http://smedisplays.com/test/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/L-Mini-Instructions.pdf";i:1;s:85:"http://smedisplays.com/test/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/L-Mini-Graphic-Template.pdf";
```

So the url is changed but the length number "81" remains the same due to which the unserialize() function is not working properly.

Is there a quick way to solve it by code because I am having around 450 posts and every single post have this meta field.

Comment: Unserialize it, change URL and serialize it again with a PHP script?

Comment: Where is this serialized data stored? Database? simple txt file? How did you change the string? How many times? because all you need to change is `i:0,s:78:"<new string here>"` and you're good to go. In case this is a db record: a simple `UPDATE WHERE field LIKE` query should do, if it's a file, then a regex search-replace is enough, or a simple command-line script that uses regex is easily written

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER your solution seems to be a feasible one let me work on that.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem The serialized data is stored in the database but yes a simple update query will work or a regex replace to the sql file. But it will only change the url not the length (number) in front of it. And that's what the real problem is.

Comment: @AbhimanueTamang: You misunderstood my comment. A simple update query in a PHP script, that executes a query like `UPDATE the_tbl SET field = :data`, and use the bind array: `array(':data' => serialize($dataWithNewUrlString));`

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem ok that's a new thing let me work on that also.

Answer (score 0):

So I have worked out a bit on @TiMESPLiNTER suggested solution and solved my problem in such a way though I was not able to understand what @EliasVanOotegem trying to suggest.

May be a working example by him will explain his solution.
And thanks to all for participating in this question.

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'product',
    'meta_key'          => '_uploaded_document',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1
);
// Fetch All posts
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        $postid = get_the_ID();
// Get the meta value       
        $meta = get_post_meta( $postid, '_uploaded_document', false );
        f(!empty($meta)){
            $instruction_sheet = $meta[0][0];
            $graphic_template = $meta[0][1];
            get_the_title();
            if( !empty($instruction_sheet) || !empty($graphic_template)){
                $new_array = array();
                if(!empty($instruction_sheet)){
// Break the URL in to an array
                    $iexplode = explode('/', $instruction_sheet);
// Replace a particular element with you string  
                    $iexplode[2]="your_string.com";
// Remove a url sting which you dont need
                    array_splice($iexplode, 3, 1);
// Combine the array to make new URL again
                    $iurl = implode('/', $iexplode);
                    $new_array[] = $iurl;
                }


                if(!empty($graphic_template)){
                    $gexplode = explode('/', $graphic_template);
                    $gexplode[2]="your_string.com";
                    array_splice($gexplode, 3, 1);
                    $gurl = implode('/', $gexplode);
                    $new_array[] = $gurl;
                }
// Generate a new serialised string
                $new_array = serialize ( $new_array);
// Update the meta value
                update_post_meta($postid, '_uploaded_document', $new_array);
            }
        }
    }
} else {
    // no posts found
}
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a very old issue but I recently faced similar issue. I was using the multi image upload plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/multi-image-upload/ and I had Godaddy backups setup. I recently needed to restore my website from godaddy using its backup. and all of a sudden the serialized images data that multi image upload stored in post meta, the unserialize wasn't working on that.
After banging my head around it for almost 2 days, I found that instead of using the "Restore" function to restore db, i needed to downloaded the sql backup, and through phpmyadmin import it and all went well.
Seems like the restore function was corrupting the serialized data.
May help someone.